# What these means in chinese language, during uninstallation of OSTOTO hotspot?

Tags: translation

Can anyone please tell me the meaning of this, during unistalling a program ?[image]

Comment: it is just a reminder saying "please don't give up on me so easily...."  if you want to continue uninstalling, click on the lower left button, if you want to cancel the uninstalling, click on the lower right button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "Please don't leave me. You said we'd always be together".

The left orange button means QQ support.

The right green button means official forum.

the left small grey button means "continue".

The right small green button means "give another chance".